# How to optimize sqlite like"%param%"

Tags: sql, sqlite, search, optimization

I saw that in the case of LIKE "hello%" you can optimize with a param >= "hello" AND param < "hellop".

I was wondering if there was something similar in the LIKE case "%hello%".

Comment: You can only do so if you have a full-text search extension.

Comment: Which sqlite [happens to have](https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html).

Comment: Also note that sqlite can in some cases automatically optimize `foo LIKE 'hello%'`. See [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57333164/9952196) for examples. But without the right indexes, just doing it yourself isn't going to help and can even produce incorrect results if you're not careful.